# Using Snappy compression with a buffer

Tags: rust, snappy

I'm trying to figure out the best way to use a buffer and [snappy](https://crates.io/crates/snappy) in Rust. Before, I was writing to a file using [`BufWriter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufWriter.html). But now I want to add compression as well. The above snappy crate's `compress` function requires a `&[u8]` as a parameter, but the `BufWriter` won't give me access to its buffer to pass to snappy. I've looked into two ways to get around this.

In the first way, I use a vector (with_capacity) instead of `BufWriter` as my buffer and created a write function that will make sure that writing to the vector won't cause it to reallocate. If it would, I instead compress what's currently in the buffer then write it out to a file and free the vector (drain function). I wrote this based off of what `BufWriter` does. The downside is that since it's a vector, if the buffer goes out of scope, it doesn't automatically flush the buffer out to the file. I have to manually do that in the scope that is writing the files, which I don't like.

In the other way, I more or less copied the `BufWriter` source code and just changed the `flush` function to compress their buffer (a vector) before outputting it to the file. This way seems the nicest, but I just don't like the idea of just copying code.

What would be the best way to proceed with these two options, or other options?

If relevant, the objects I write into the buffer are always the same size and my buffer size is a multiple of the object size.

Comment: Is snappy compatible with compressing multiple buffers and then packing them all together? The function signature seems to indicate that it expects to compress and decompress everything in one shot. If that's the case, you'd need to buffer everything (into a `Vec<u8>`) and then compress it all at the end.

Comment: You're right. I initially thought that since I know that the uncompressed size would be constant, I would also be able to separate the buffers and decompress them one by one. But knowing the uncompressed size won't help me because the compressed size won't be constant. 

I'll try using a `Vec,u8>` and see how that impacts performance. Thanks.

Also, how should I deal with this question stackoverflow-wise? Should I delete it, or is there a way to mark it resolved without selecting an answer?

Comment: I think that the way you've asked the question there is an answer, so I'll post my answer in the next hour or two. The answer just won't do exactly what you wanted :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like snappy needs to compress all in one go, you will just need to buffer everything up until the end. You can then flush and compress at the end:

```
use std::io::{self, Write, Cursor};

fn compress(_data: &[u8]) -> Vec<u8> {
    // The best compression ever
    b"compressed".as_ref().into()
}

struct SnappyCompressor<W> {
    inner: W,
    buffer: Vec<u8>,
}

impl<W> SnappyCompressor<W>
    where W: Write
{
    fn new(inner: W) -> Self {
        SnappyCompressor {
            inner: inner,
            buffer: vec![],
        }
    }
}

impl<W> Write for SnappyCompressor<W>
    where W: Write
{
    fn write(&mut self, data: &[u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
        self.buffer.extend(data);
        Ok(data.len())
    }

    fn flush(&mut self) -> io::Result<()> {
        let compressed = compress(&self.buffer);
        self.inner.write_all(&compressed)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut output = Cursor::new(vec![]);
    {
        let mut compressor = SnappyCompressor::new(output.by_ref());
        assert_eq!(5, compressor.write(b"hello").unwrap());
        assert_eq!(5, compressor.write(b"world").unwrap());
        compressor.flush().unwrap();
    }
    let bytes = output.into_inner();
    assert_eq!(&b"compressed"[..], &bytes[..]);
}
```

This solution has one big questionable aspect — we are using `flush` to mark the end of the stream, but that's not really the meaning of that method. It would probably be far better to use a purely streaming compressor, but sometimes you gotta do what you gotta do.

There's also a few landmines:

1. You have to explicitly call `flush`
2. You can't call `flush` twice.

To allow the user to simply drop the compressor and have it be finalized, you can implement `Drop`:

```
impl<W> Drop for SnappyCompressor<W>
    where W: Write
{
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.flush().unwrap();
    }
}
```

To prevent attempting flushing twice, you need to add a flag to track that:

```
fn write(&mut self, data: &[u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
    if self.is_flushed {
        return Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, "Buffer has already been compressed, cannot add more data"));
    }

    self.buffer.extend(data);
    Ok(data.len())
}

fn flush(&mut self) -> io::Result<()> {
    if self.is_flushed {
        return Ok(())
    }

    self.is_flushed = true;
    let compressed = compress(&self.buffer);
    self.inner.write_all(&compressed)
}
```

All together, the final version looks like:

```
use std::io::{self, Write, Cursor, Error, ErrorKind};

fn compress(_data: &[u8]) -> Vec<u8> {
    // The best compression ever
    b"compressed".as_ref().into()
}

struct SnappyCompressor<W>
    where W: Write
{
    inner: W,
    buffer: Vec<u8>,
    is_flushed: bool,
}

impl<W> SnappyCompressor<W>
    where W: Write
{
    fn new(inner: W) -> Self {
        SnappyCompressor {
            inner: inner,
            buffer: vec![],
            is_flushed: false,
        }
    }

    // fn into_inner
}

impl<W> Write for SnappyCompressor<W>
    where W: Write
{
    fn write(&mut self, data: &[u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
        if self.is_flushed {
            return Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, "Buffer has already been compressed, cannot add more data"));
        }

        self.buffer.extend(data);
        Ok(data.len())
    }

    fn flush(&mut self) -> io::Result<()> {
        if self.is_flushed {
            return Ok(())
        }

        self.is_flushed = true;
        let compressed = compress(&self.buffer);
        self.inner.write_all(&compressed)
    }
}

impl<W> Drop for SnappyCompressor<W>
    where W: Write
{
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.flush().unwrap();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut output = Cursor::new(vec![]);
    {
        let mut compressor = SnappyCompressor::new(output.by_ref());
        assert_eq!(5, compressor.write(b"hello").unwrap());
        assert_eq!(5, compressor.write(b"world").unwrap());
        compressor.flush().unwrap();
    }
    let bytes = output.into_inner();
    assert_eq!(&b"compressed"[..], &bytes[..]);
}
```

Comment: This looks good as something that more or less answered my question. I'll try this, and something else, out and see how they perform. Thanks again!